# Laravel eloquent, defining different users/roles

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm working on an app where we have a table called Articles, in this table we need to know the writer of the article as well as the admin who published it or gave the permission to publish it. so initially for each article  we have the following

```
ID
Title
Body
```

Both the admin and the writer are users where they have their attributes in the Users table and are distinguished based on the Roles they have. We have Roles that are assigned to each user such as writer, admin, reader...etc

How can I know for each article who wrote it and who approved it.

Comment: Either add columns with specified attributes or add a table which tracks this (then you could have much more info, such as who edited the post last etc.).

Comment: So basically, you think I should add to more columns such as, writer_ID and Admin_ID? or a third table to form many-to-many relationship?

Comment: I would definitely add `writer_id` or `created_by_user_id` or something similar to add the relation to the user who created the article. The admin who published really depends on your use case. If you need the specific action (who published) visible very often, add a column like `published_by_user_id` and put in the ID when the admin publishes. If you only need to track it occasionally, you are more flexible with an additional table like @KiprasT mentioned